# Что хранится в указателе до инициализации? C++

Tags: c++, указатели, static

Есть класс в котором есть **статическое** поле, являющееся указателем. Что хранится в этом поле? Можно ли как-то инициализировать это поле-указатель по умолчанию нулем? Пример кода:

```
class A {
public:
    static int* m_ptr;
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
static int* m_ptr = 0;
```

Но пишет, что поле с инициализатором внутри класса должен быть const

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/185848/5011111 тут чето похожее

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Спасибо, но что с первой частью вопроса? Что хранится в указателе до инициализации нулем? Мусор? Или сразу ноль?

Comment: А если делать его не `const`, а `inline`? Просто в классе - это объявление, а определение должно быть вне класса. Но `inline` должен вас спасти. Ну, или напишите, как вы написали - только *вне* класса, как `static int* A::m_ptr = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все нелокальные объекты со статической продолжительностью хранения (в том числе и статические переменные-члены класса) по умолчанию инициализируются нулевым значением (*zero-initialized*).

Статические переменные-члены класса также должны быть определены ровно в одном модуле трансляции — в противном случае это вызовет ошибку линковки. Синтаксис определения будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
int *A::m_ptr;
```

Соответственно инициализировать их можно при определении:

```
int *A::m_ptr = (int *) 0xDEADBEEF;
```

---

В C++17 также появился синтаксис `inline static`:

```
class A {
public:
    inline static int* m_ptr = (int *) 0xDEADBEEF;
}
```

---

Подробности про инициализацию переменных на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables).

Comment: Занудство: инициализация указателя числом не скомпилируется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ты технически прав, а, как известно, это лучший вид правоты...